# add special characters in a text using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file which is :

```
line1
line2
line3
```

What I am trying to have is

```
"line1"{
"line1"
 }
```

I am trying to do this using awk but I don't know how to use the special characters. For now I have this.

```
awk '{ "$0" {"$0"} }'
```

Comment: Usually, special characters are escaped using a backslash.

Comment: please use code tags for expected output also, it is being shown as single line instead of multiple lines.. also, could you explain the transformation process? do you want to transform only first line and ignore others? etc

Comment: I want to transform every line. I want to have : ''line1''
 {
    "line1'' }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk '{$0="\""$0"\""; print $0 "{\n" $0 "\n}"}' file
"line1"{
"line1"
}
"line2"{
"line2"
}
"line3"{
"line3"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -v q='"' '{ql = q $0 q; print ql "{" ORS ql ORS "}" }' ip.txt
"line1"{
"line1"
}
"line2"{
"line2"
}
"line3"{
"line3"
}
```

- `-v q='"'` save the double quote character in variable named `q`, makes it easier to insert double quotes instead of messing with escapes
- `ql = q $0 q` this adds double quotes around the input record
- `ql "{" ORS ql ORS "}"` required output, `ORS` is output record separator which is newline character by default

  - space between the different parameters is ignored, use `" }"` to get a space before `}` in the output

Answer (score 2):

as a comparison with `sed`

```
$ sed 's/.*/"&"{\n"&"\n}/' file

"line1"{
"line1"
}
"line2"{
"line2"
}
"line3"{
"line3"
}
```

also another `awk`

```
$ awk -v OFS="\n" -v q='"' '{v=q $0 q; print v "{", v, "}" }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `printf`:

```
awk -v fmt='"%s"{\n"%s"\n}\n' '{printf fmt, $0,$0 }' file
```

Test with your data:

```
kent$  awk -v fmt='"%s"{\n"%s"\n}\n' '{printf fmt, $0,$0 }' f
"line1"{
"line1"
}
"line2"{
"line2"
}
"line3"{
"line3"
}
```